# Rolling joins (LOCF) in Postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, data.table

Over time, I have gotten used to the incredibly useful functionality of `data.table`'s rolling joins in `r`.  These utilize the operation of `LOCF` (last observation carried forward).  Unfortunately, I am forced to work in a environment that I am much less familiar with (using `postgres`).  Is there an analogous operation in SQL (specifically `postgres`)?

Here is an example of what I have and the output I would like:

Here is my first table

```
dt1 = data.table(Date=seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-03"),
         to=as.Date("2013-06-27"), by="1 day"),key="Date")[, ind:=.I]

           Date ind
  1: 2013-01-03   1
  2: 2013-01-04   2
  3: 2013-01-05   3
  4: 2013-01-06   4
  5: 2013-01-07   5
 ---               
172: 2013-06-23 172
173: 2013-06-24 173
174: 2013-06-25 174
175: 2013-06-26 175
176: 2013-06-27 176
```

Here is my second table

```
dt2 = data.table(Date=seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-01"),
         to=as.Date("2013-06-30"), by="1 week"),key="Date")

          Date
 1: 2013-01-01
 2: 2013-01-08
 3: 2013-01-15
 4: 2013-01-22
 5: 2013-01-29
 ---
22: 2013-05-28
23: 2013-06-04
24: 2013-06-11
25: 2013-06-18
26: 2013-06-25
```

Here is the code I would use in `data.table` for the desired output.

```
dt1[dt2, roll=Inf]

          Date ind
 1: 2013-01-01  NA
 2: 2013-01-08   6
 3: 2013-01-15  13
 4: 2013-01-22  20
 5: 2013-01-29  27
---
22: 2013-05-28 146
23: 2013-06-04 153
24: 2013-06-11 160
25: 2013-06-18 167
26: 2013-06-25 174
```

Is this even possible using `postgres` (or more generally speaking, `SQL`?  Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: What do the values in column "ind" mean?

Comment: It is simply a value to confirm that the join is being done correctly. In this case, is basically signifies the row number.

Comment: If it just confirms that the join is being done correctly, can't you just use the second table by itself? The values in the column "Date" are identical.

Comment: I am trying to merge the "ind" column on to dt2.  This might be an oversimplification of the problem, but I want to be able to merge on date even if two dates are exactly equal.  I would like values to be "carried forward."

Answer (score 4):

I'd really be interested to see if someone can do this without populating the full cross-join table first. But here's a solution with cross join:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f3f/3/0

Create the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`t1` double, `ind` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`t1`, `ind`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1.9, 2),
    (3.1, 3),
    (4, 4),
    (5.1, 5),
    (5.9, 6)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`t2` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`t2`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6)
;
```

Query:

```
select t2, max(ind)
from (select t2, ind
      from table1
      cross join table2
      where t1 <= t2) as foo
group by t2
```

Result:

```
T2  MAX(IND)
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   4
5   4
6   6
```

EDIT: @Hadley's comment is correct, that the full cross join table is never materialized using the query above, as the query above produces the same explain and results as the query below:

```
select t2, max(ind)
from table1
cross join table2
where t1 <= t2
group by t2
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure postgres never realises the full join (cross is actually the default behaviour), but you'd want to check that by using explain (provided you've set up some reasonable indices)

Comment: Looks like this works here.  I will now try on my much larger data-sets to see how it scales.  Thanks!

Comment: So does this mean that the full cross-join table is never populated?

Comment: @Mike.Gahan In PostgreSQL (at least), I am pretty sure that that is the case. To test, I used PGAdmin and looked at the Explain visualizations. But the real test will be when the query is run on your large dataset. I'd be interested to hear how that goes.

Answer (score 4):

Since I am working in a special `Postgres` environment, apparently it does not allow me to cross join.  Thanks so much to @Clayton Stanley for the great answer, but I had to try another route.  It looks to be working so far.  I apologize for not being able to perform time comparisons of both methods.

Create the schema

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int,`t1` double, `ind` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`,`t1`, `ind`)
VALUES
    (1,0.99, 5),
    (1,1.90, 10),
    (2,3.10, 12),
    (2,4.00, 3),
    (3,5.10, 8),
    (3,5.90, 16),
    (4,5.90, 7),
    (4,5.99, 20)
;



CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`id` int, `t2` double)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`id`,`t2`)
VALUES
    (1,1.00),
    (2,3.95),
    (3,5.05),
    (4,6.01)
;
```

Perform the join using subqueries

```
select B.*
from Table2 as A
join Table1 as B
on B.id=A.id
join(
    select 
       SUBB.id,
       max(SUBB.t1) as t1
    from Table2 as SUBA
    join Table1 as SUBB
    on SUBB.id=SUBA.id and
    SUBB.t1 <= SUBA.t2
    group by SUBB.id
    )
as subqry
on B.t1=subqry.t1  and
   A.id=subqry.id
```

The example schema and output is here:

[Link to schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4210/1)